# Handling selected items from a checkable menu

Tags: java, android, submenu

I am using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072347/how-to-select-multiple-checkboxes-in-submenu-on-android?answertab=active#tab-top) tutorial to create a submenu with checkable items. So, far everything works but I can't figure out how to handle the selected items as I am new to serializable. This is the link to the tutorial

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072347/how-to-select-multiple-checkboxes-in-submenu-on-android?answertab=active#tab-top

```
   public static final String SETTING_CHECK_BOX = "SETTING_CHECK_BOX";

private ArrayList < SettingCheckBox > settingList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... 
    settingList = new ArrayList < SettingCheckBox > ();
    settingList.add ( new SettingCheckBox ( "Option A" ) );
    settingList.add ( new SettingCheckBox ( "Option B" ) );
    // ... add more items
    // restore any previously saved list
    if ( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        settingList = (ArrayList < SettingCheckBox >) savedInstanceState.getSerializable ( SETTING_CHECK_BOX );
    }
    // ...
}

         protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data ) {
            if ( resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null )
                return;
            settingList = (ArrayList < SettingCheckBox >) data.getSerializableExtra ( SETTING_CHECK_BOX );

    //how can I log print the list of items that have been checked
    // What should go here ? such that i can do other things after getting a list of items that were checked ?

     //This is my try

            Object[] mStringArray = settingList.toArray();

               for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
               Log.d("***Checked items*",(String)mStringArray[i]);
         }

        }
```

Comment: I think the `data.getSerializableExtra ( SETTING_CHECK_BOX );` is fine when retrieving the data. If ever you decided to proceed with it, try my answer again (adding the checker `if settingList.get(i).isChecked()` while iterating). I'm pretty sure it's correct. Cheers!

Comment: `Log.i("***Context Menu*", String.valueOf(settingList.get(i).getChecked()));` gave me all the list as true which were checked and false which weren't . Now, trying to get description using if else statement.

Comment: Yup. Just put the `if else` statement as I mentioned in my previous comment in my answer. And I think it's all okay by then. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error from that code? If not, it means that your `settingList` is properly initialized with the parsed value from `data.getSerializableExtra ( SETTING_CHECK_BOX );`, which is a list of `SettingCheckBox` object. From the link you provided, the code for `SettingCheckBox` object class is included. What you do with the data inside the object depends on your use case.

---

**EDIT**: In response to comments.

If by ***names***, you mean the `SettingCheckBox` text description, you can iterate over your `settingList` directly like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < settingList.size(); i++){
    Log.d("***Checked items*", settingList.get(i).getDescription());
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code under //this is my try.  Basically I want the names of all the items that were checked.

Comment: Yes, by names I meant the text description in SettingCheckBox, with the code you have provided I simply get all the items i initially added in ArrayList irrespective of their status (checked or unchecked ). Please check my edit.  I was hoping if you could help me get just the items that was checked.

Comment: @choman I see. You can then just make use of the getter function of `SettingCheckBox` -- `getChecked()`. In the iteration, add an `if` statement. If `true`, print the description.

Comment: @McAwesomeville , Hey! thanx for the tip.I am currently looking into it but as i can't produce the result. So, I am following this tutorial now http://eugeneandroid.blogspot.com/2014/12/android-listview-with-checkbox-custom.html . I am trying to get a result like that of the   Toast of button.setOnClickListener under Mainactivity. I have not been able to replicate the result in my project however.

Comment: I believe the the data is already there under **Intent data** of  `protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data ` )  Can you help me retrieve it ?

Comment: You're already retrieving it with `settingList = (ArrayList < SettingCheckBox >) data.getSerializableExtra ( SETTING_CHECK_BOX );` Unless it doesn't reach the code because if the `Intent data` is null, it will call `return;`

Comment: i get a yellow warning in `(ArrayList <SettingCheckBox>)` under `settingList = (ArrayList < SettingCheckBox >) data.getSerializableExtra ( SETTING_CHECK_BOX );` which reads This cast is unsafe because it is not possible to check at runtime wether an instance of type 'java.io.serializable' is of type 'java.util.ArrayList<com.red.choman.Activity.SettingCheckBox>'  . I am pretty sure the code you have provide is working as i checked the debug windows and i have the data but its something like com.red.choman.activity.SettingCheckbox@2534ebs and not the title of the text box.

Comment: You are getting the not yet serialized version. You can go ahead and test it out. I tried it on my end and I also see the yellow warning. But since you are using the object class `SettingCheckBox`, I think it would be fine. It's up to you if you want further checking to be added. :)

Comment: Okay thanx, I will work on it again & post out the result.

Answer (score 0):

@McAwesomville , hey thank you for all the help.Got it working! This is the code I came up with after your suggestions :) Cheers!

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null)
            return;
        settingList = (ArrayList<SettingCheckBox>) data.getSerializableExtra(SETTING_CHECK_BOX);

        for (int i = 0; i <settingList.size(); i++){
            if (settingList.get(i).getChecked()){
                Log.d("**Checked Item**",String.valueOf(settingList.get(i).getDescription()));
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Your welcome. Well. It's just similar to my answer. Plus the detail in the comments. Anyways. You should select an accepted answer. You can accept your own answer or my answer. Just to tag it as properly answered. Cheers! :D