# Multiple selection on menu checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, menu

I'm trying to create a menu with filters on a map, the idea is to select multiple elements (like the screenshoot). But the problem is that every time I press an option, the menu is automatically hidden.

So I can only tap one checkbox everytime I open the menu. This behaviour is not the best because user has to open N times the menu to select N filters.

**Any suggestion or advice about how to solve this? Thanks!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And this is my code (reduced to be more readable):

**map_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_filtro"
        app:showAsAction="always" >

        <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ciencia"
            android:icon="@drawable/ciencia"
            android:title="@string/filtro_ciencia"
            app:showAsAction="never"

             />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_comercio"
            android:icon="@drawable/comercio"
            android:title="@string/filtro_comercio"
            app:showAsAction="never"
             />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_cultura"
            android:icon="@drawable/cultura"
            android:title="@string/filtro_cultura"
            app:showAsAction="never"
             />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_deporte"
            android:icon="@drawable/deporte"
            android:title="@string/filtro_deportes"
            app:showAsAction="never"
             />
        </group>
        </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_drawer, menu);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        MenuItem item_ciencia = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_ciencia);
        item_ciencia.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_ciencia, false));
        MenuItem item_comercio = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_comercio);
        item_comercio.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_comercio, false));
        MenuItem item_cultura = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_cultura);
        item_cultura.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_cultura, false));
        MenuItem item_deporte = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_deporte);
        item_deporte.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_deporte, false));
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }else  if (id == R.id.nav_ciencia) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_ciencia, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_comercio) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_comercio, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cultura) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_cultura, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_deporte) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.pref_nav_deporte, item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        } 

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: hey checkout this answer may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072347/how-to-select-multiple-checkboxes-in-submenu-on-android

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MaheshKeshvala , I'll try it!

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Ping. Any solution here?